# How can i create a folder inside the shared volume with the correct permission in docker?

Tags: drupal, containers, docker

I have a problem with docker container.

The Container i used have apache+Mysql+Ubuntu system and I want to run drupal on it.

And I used shared volume to shared all the drupal files with the host os for backup purpose.

but I meet a problem that I can't make any folder in the shared folder with the correct permission.

Just like

```
mkdir example;
chmod -R 777 example;
```

But the permission of folder is still not change.

How can i fix this?

Comment: You can use `docker cp` to copy files from a container to the host instead of using a volume.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue (mac os -> vagrant -> docker). Not sure whether you can easily fix the root cause, but the workarounds that helped me were:

1. The cleanest option is to configure the application to write to folders outside the mounted host directory, most probably to `/tmp`.
2. When the previous option is not very feasible you can try and add a mount inside mapped directory, e.g. `-v /my_host_projects/my_drupal_project/:/my_drupal_project:ro -v /my_drupal_project/tmp_hardcoding_is_evil/`. This feels rather hacky though.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But i still have problem on files folder. It need permission 777 that the system can put the img or css in that folder.If this problem can be fixed. the mounted method really help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using boot to docker? If so I think your are running into [boot2docker issue 587](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/587). Basically virtual box which is used to bring up the VM for boot2docker does not support POSIX permissions editing. This should work fine in a linux environment or VM which you would probably be using for your production deployment. Does make testing a pain I guess.

Comment: Yes, I am using boot2docker.The issue you provided really helpful. Thanks a lot.